# How can I push commit to Gerrit if "committer email address does not match your user account"?

Tags: gerrit, http-authentication, access-rights

Gerrit type auth is http (apache2 uses for authentification (file user-password) )

When I try 
**push origin HEAD:refs/for/master** 
I have error:

```
remote: ERROR:  In commit 21875449d592efeb74543b836d7967e12befc944
remote: ERROR:  committer email address Workspace@Workspace-PC
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  You have not registered any email addresses.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  https://my_gerrit_site:4432/gerrit/#/settings/contact
```

When I try to Register New email I have "500 Internal server error" (as I understand this error is related with gerrit type auth).
If I belong to the group Administrators I dont have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I belong to the group DEV and I added some Access rights to the project:

```
Reference: refs/heads/*
Forge Committer Identity
ALLOW DEV
```

and it helped me